# Проблема со связью моделей

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

у меня проблема со связью моделей в Django.

```
User = get_user_model()

class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Название", max_length=75)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Пользователь", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Playground(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Название", max_length=75)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, verbose_name="Турнир", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

При создании миграции выдает ошибку

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "kvantorium_tournaments_playground" referencing "kvantorium_tournaments_tournament"
```

**На всякий случай ниже весь код (Может полезен будет)**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class Teacher(models.Model):
    fio = models.CharField(verbose_name="ФИО", max_length=125, db_index=True)
    TYPE_KVANTUM = (
        (1, "Автоквантум"),
        (2, "Аэроквантум"),
        (3, "Биоквантум"),
        (4, "Промробоквантум"),
        (5, "Хайтек"),
        (6, "IT-квантум"),
        (7, "Админквантум")
    )
    kvantum = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Квантум", choices=TYPE_KVANTUM)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name="Пользователь", on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Child(models.Model):
    fio = models.CharField(verbose_name="ФИО", max_length=125)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    numClass = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Класс")
    school = models.CharField(verbose_name="Школа", max_length=255)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name="Пользователь", on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Название", max_length=75)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Пользователь", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Playground(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Название", max_length=75)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, verbose_name="Турнир", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Criteria(models.Model):
    playground = models.ForeignKey(Playground, verbose_name="Площадка", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Название", max_length=75)
    points = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Баллы")

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Название", max_length=75)
    points = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Баллы")

class OfChildInTeam(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=1)
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, verbose_name="Дети", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name="Команда", on_delete=models.CASCAD)
```

Comment: единственное, что у меня вызвало ошибку в этом коде, это недописанная последняя строчка в месте models.CASCADE

Попробуйте снести все миграции и базу (если есть такая возможность) и накатить миграцию вновь

Answer (score 0):

Расширять модель пользователя лучше в другом приложении.
примерно так. https://habr.com/ru/post/313764/ (2 способ будет хорош)

```
autor = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Пользователь')
```

про строчку `on_delete=models.CASCAD` - согласен с предыдущим оратором

Answer (score 0):

Помогло удаление db.sqlite3 и удаление файлов из папки migrations.
И заново прописать migrate